# What are the best parameters for W0lf miner with a R9 380 GPU?

Tags: mining

I'm unsure wich parameter I should use to get the best hashrate with mit R9 380 GPUS.

```
                "corefreq": 500,
                "memfreq": 1500,
                "fanspeed": 65,
                "powertune": 20,
                "threads": 1,
                "rawintensity": 640,
                "worksize": 16

                "index": -1,
                "threads": 2,
                "rawintensity": 16, "worksize": 16
```

Answer (score 2):

the only parameters that actually change anything are rawintensity and worksize. try increasing rawintensity a little bit at a time until it the miner crashes, then back off. you could also change worksize down to 8 and then repeat increasing the rawintensity.